# nhibernate connectionstring centralization strategy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nhibernate, connection-string

We have a large VS solution, consisting of many projects representing the various model, service and presentation layers.

Currently the connection string to the main database is spread throughout the solution. On the web front end, its contained in the web.config file. The data initialization and web forms app have it contained in separate nhibernate.config files.

Is there a better way to manage the connection string?

I was thinking if somehow it was centralized in one point, it would then be easier to manage and update, rather than having it spread all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is to have only one place in the solution where the connection string need be specified, then the following should work.

Split out the connection strings section into a separate file and reference it in the configuration files that you need to using

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
```

Now put connectionStrings.config file in a common location (perhaps Solution Items). Add it as a link to each project that requires it using [`Add Existing Item -> Add as Link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Because all of the projects now have a link to the one connectionStrings.config file, any changes to that file should propagate to the linked items in each project in the solution.

Comment: In a scenario where a project goes from Debug to Release, and each stage has a different database, is this configsource strategy compatible with web.config transformations?

Comment: It is yes - in the web config transforms for Release however you would replace the `<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>` to reference a different connections string config file i.e. web.release.config would contain `<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings-release.config" xdt:Transform="Replace" />` and `connectionStrings-release.config` file would contain your release connection strings

Comment: One final consideration for a centralized connection string, would it be accessible to a fluent nhibernate configuration?

Comment: Yes use the `FromConnectionStringWithKey` method